# Three.js keep object static relative to outside container div - EDIT now with jsfiddle

Tags: three.js

So I have the basic setup of a three.js-canvas rendered inside of a html-div. Inside the 3d-world I want to position an object in such a way that it appears to be glued on to this outside div (should never move in any way). Currently I have this solution:

```
render {    
    object.position.x = camera.position.x;
    object.position.y = camera.position.y;
    object.position.z = camera.position.z - 200;
}
```

This works for panning the camera (i have rotation disabled since i don't need it). However, once I zoom in or out it obviously doesn't work any more, since zooming doesn't change the camera's position values. My approach was to incorporate the camera.zoom factor into the above function, but i couldn't get it to work properly. Is there an easy transformation function or something i can use?

**Edit**: I created a jsfiddle, hopefully this helps figuring out the solution. As long as you pan the camera with right mouse the yellow plane doesn't move at all (wanted behaviour). When you zoom in or out it starts to move (unwanted behaviour): https://jsfiddle.net/rdyLp7uc/2/

Comment: Sorry I don't have the answer, but repositioning the object from the camera frustrum seems strange honestly. Wouldn't be better (easier, at least) to constrain the camera position on a virtual (object_position, initial_camera_position) line ?

Comment: Hey thanks for the input but I can't fully understand your comment. I want to be able to pan and zoom the camera unconstrained and just fix the position of the yellow element.

Comment: You could simply use a standard html element...

Comment: Hmm would an html element inside the scene correctly affect the 3d elements within it? I want the yellow plane to be a kind of clipping plane that vertically cuts through the entire scene, slicing objects at its location that come in contact with it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the blue dots are in front